# make half jframe transparent using java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, translucency

I am creating a `JFrame` Form using Netbeans .Is it possible to make transparent half portion of the `JFrame` and the remaining half portion as the same .
If i use opacity property it applies on the full portion of the `JFrame`

How is possible to make some portion of the `JFrame` transparent using java swing.

Comment: try to set background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using a non transparent panel for the half of the frame that you don't want to be transparent and the rest you could use setOpacity();

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this isn't possible. It's all or nothing.
To achieve the effect you're describing you'll want to make the `JFrame` fully transparent as you are doing. Then put two `JPanel` inside; make one `JPanel` opaque and the other transparent.

**Edit**
After a bit of internetting, I believe this actually *can* be done to some extent. Using [`GradientPaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html) in a custom `paint` function, you could probably achieve something to this effect.

However, this approach would be, in my opinion, harder to achieve, harder to maintain, less intuitive and less legible.

Comment: is it possible to make jpanel transparent

Comment: Yup, `JComponent` specifies [setOpaque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque(boolean)).

Comment: but that way you cant specify how opaque the panel should be

Comment: setOpaque doesn't works for translucency AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(), I don't know how to answering this question, because AWT Components are transparent too, only background image can do that